Conditional distribution depending only on a statistic
Suppose $(X,Y)$ is a random variable such that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Let $(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_n,Y_n)$ be $n$ i.i.d. copies. Define $W := S(X_1,Y_1,...,X_n,Y_n)$ for some function $S$. If the conditional distribution of $W|X_1,...,X_n$ does not depend on $X_1,...,X_n$ themselve but only on some function $T(X_1,...,X_n)$, is it true that $W|T$ has the same distribution as $W|X_1,...,X_n$? How can we prove it (preferably without measure theory)?

$$
\mathbb{P}(W\le a\mid X_1,\dots,X_n)=G(T(X_1,\dots,X_n),a)
$$
for some function $G$ by the condition. By the law of iterated expectation,
$$
\mathbb{P}(W\le a\mid T(X_1,\dots,X_n))
=
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(W\le a\mid T(X_1,\dots,X_n),X_1,\dots,X_n)\mid T(X_1,\dots,X_n)]
=
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(W\le a\mid X_1,\dots,X_n)\mid T(X_1,\dots,X_n)]
=
\mathbb{E}[G(T(X_1,\dots,X_n),a)\mid T(X_1,\dots,X_n)]
=
G(T(X_1,\dots,X_n),a),
$$
so the answer is "yes".

The only part I don't understand is why $P(W \le a | T(X_1,...,X_n)) = E[P(W \le a | T(X_1,...,X_n),X_1,...,X_n)|T(X_1,....,X_n)]$?

This is the law of iterated expectation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) with extra conditioning on $T$ (as $\mathbb{E}(1_{W\le a})=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(1_{W\le a}\mid X_1,...,X_n))$ and the fact that $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)=\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X,h(X))$ for any function $h(x)$.
